# How does the jQuery get() method support flexible parameter indices?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `get()` method in jQuery has the following signature:

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

However, it supports both:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) { ... } );
```

and

```
$.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

**How is this possible?** As someone with only basic working knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery, I'm curious how this function can be overloaded to support arguments in what seems to be a very flexible manner.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L832

Comment: Thank you @KevinB - the "Shift arguments if data argument was omitted" is pretty much what I expected to see. I was hunting for the method in the source but didn't know where to start. Feel free to add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By determining if a parameter is of a particular type, the parameters can be made optional and flexible. JQuery knows that if the parameter is an object, then it is data. If it is a function, then it is a callback.

Comment: The comparison actually goes the other way, since data can be an object, array, string, or even formdata, so it's easier to just check whether or not it is a function.